# Dismiss View Controller inside UITabController

Tags: ios, swift3, uitabbarcontroller

I've a project which contains a tab controller, as the main 'page'.

I want to add a UITabBar button item, which presents a view controller modaly, and within that view controller, add a dismiss button that dismisses that view controller and returns to the previous tab selection.

To clarify, it's something that the Medium app for iOS uses, when you click on the create post item, it presents it modaly and dismisses it when you want to.

I can present the view controller, but I can't dismiss it.

Hope I made myself understandable.

Example:
[image: Pressing the middle button]

Comment: I've read around here that I could add a empty tab as placeholder then add a button as it's subview then in the button property I could call the viewcontroller modaly. But how can I add a empty tab as a placeholder ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've managed to solve this as I wanted to, hope the answer will help someone in the future.

First of all, I set on my first loaded view controller, lets say my 'Home' view controller the `tabBarController` delegate to be my AppDelegate.swift file (this is personal preference), as:

```
self.tabBarController?.delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? UITabBarControllerDelegate
```

Then in my `AppDelegate.swift` file i added to the class properties the delegate `UITabBarControllerDelegate` so I could access the `tabBarController` delegate functions, such as

`func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {}`

Then edited the function to interact with my specific view controller.

The final version of the function:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if viewController is ViewControllerToPresentModaly {
        if let newVC = tabBarController.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "modalVC") {
            tabBarController.present(newVC, animated: true)
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Here if you want the regular tab behaviour, `return true` or your own `return false`

;)